# Generelize a type to a system of types in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns, parametric-polymorphism

I have some code where there is such object as **Event**, it has a collection of **Attributes**, which has values which anyone can get by calling the **Event method**: ***Double getAttributeValue(Integer index)***.
Until now AtributeValue as in the method's signature was always Double. Now it can be other new Classes and I need to generalize the code so everywhere where any operators applied on Double should work on my new system of classes. Moreover the classes should operate not only as in the old code, one to same class, but also interact with same operators between one to another. 
for exmaple, the old code operated like this:

```
private Double calculateDelta(Event event) {
        Double firstValue = (Double)event.getAttributeValue(StockEventTypesManager.firstStockMeasurementIndex);
        Double secondValue = (Double)event.getAttributeValue(StockEventTypesManager.firstStockMeasurementIndex + 1);
        return Math.abs(firstValue - secondValue);
    }
```

The new code should operate something like this:

```
private AttributeValue calculateDelta(Event event) {
        AttributeValue firstValue = (AttributeValue )event.getAttributeValue(StockEventTypesManager.firstStockMeasurementIndex);
        AttributeValue secondValue = (AttributeValue )event.getAttributeValue(StockEventTypesManager.firstStockMeasurementIndex + 1);
        return Math.abs(AttrValueFunctional.minus(firstValue,secondValue));
    }
```

or something like this (those just suggestions, because I don't know how to design it):

```
private AttributeValue calculateDelta(Event event) {
            AttributeValue firstValue = (AttributeValue )event.getAttributeValue(StockEventTypesManager.firstStockMeasurementIndex);
            AttributeValue secondValue = (AttributeValue )event.getAttributeValue(StockEventTypesManager.firstStockMeasurementIndex + 1);
            return (firstValue.minus(secondValue)).abs();
    }
```

where this code can be corresponding to each one of those pairs of statements:

```
boolean isDoubleWrapper = firstValue isinstanceof DoubleWrapper; //true
boolean isDoubleList = secondValue isinstanceof DoublePairsList; //true

boolean isDoubleList = firstValue isinstanceof DoublePairsList; //true
boolean isDoubleWrapper = secondValue isinstanceof DoubleWrapper; //true

boolean isDoubleWrapper = firstValue isinstanceof DoubleWrapper; //true
boolean isDoubleWrapper = secondValue isinstanceof DoubleWrapper; //true

boolean isDoublePairsList = firstValue isinstanceof DoublePairsList; //true
boolean isDoublePairsList = secondValue isinstanceof DoublePairsList; //true
```

it also could be:

```
boolean isStrangeObject = firstValue isinstanceof StrangeObject; //true
boolean isDoubleList = secondValue isinstanceof DoublePairsList; //true

boolean isDoubleList = firstValue isinstanceof DoublePairsList; //true
boolean isStrangeObject = secondValue isinstanceof StrangeObject; //true

boolean isStrangeObject = firstValue isinstanceof StrangeObject; //true
boolean isStrangeObject = secondValue isinstanceof StrangeObject; //true

boolean isDoublePairsList = firstValue isinstanceof DoublePairsList; //true
boolean isDoublePairsList = secondValue isinstanceof DoublePairsList; //true
```

My great design goal is to make it possible to any coder in the future easily add some new classes which could "hide" in AttributeValue, add the needed operational functionality (add, subtract, abs),
so there should be good scalability to new classes.

I tried some implementations, one of them generally works (the one showed below), but I don't think it's following the best java design patterns or it has good scalability and easy to add new classes ass I mentioned.

```
public class Main {
    public interface Operand {}

    public interface Combiner<T> {
        T subtract(T a, T b);
    }

    public static abstract class MyFunctional {

        public static<T extends Operand> T
        compute(Operand a, Operand b, Subtracter combiner) {
            return (T) combiner.subtract(a, b);
        }

        private static A subtractAA(A a, A b){
            return new A(a.getFirst() - b.getFirst(), a.getSecond()-b.getSecond());
        }

        private static A subtractAB(A a, B b){
            return new A(a.getFirst() - b.getFirst(), a.getSecond()-b.getSecond()-b.getThird());
        }

        static class
        Subtracter implements Combiner<Operand> {
            @Override
            public Operand subtract(Operand x, Operand y) {

                if(x instanceof A && y instanceof A){
                    return subtractAA((A)x,(A)y);
                }
                if(x instanceof A && y instanceof B){
                    return subtractAB((A)x,(B)y);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

    }


    public static class A implements Operand{
        private int a;
        private int b;

        public A(int a, int b){
            this.a=a;
            this.b=b;
        }
        public int getFirst(){
            return a;
        }

        public int getSecond() {
            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "("+a+" "+b+")";
        }
    }

    public static class B implements Operand {
        private int a;
        private int b;
        private int c;

        public B(int a, int b, int c){
            this.a=a;
            this.b=b;
            this.c = c;
        }
        public int getFirst(){
            return a;
        }

        public int getSecond() {
            return b;
        }

        public int getThird() {
            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "("+a+" "+b+" "+c+")";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Operand e = new A(1, 2);
        Operand f = new A(3,4);
        Operand g = new B(3,4,5);
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        System.out.println((Object)MyFunctional.compute(e,f, new MyFunctional.Subtracter()));

        Operand o = MyFunctional.compute(f,g, new MyFunctional.Subtracter());

        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}
```

That's a kind of a small example of what I tried to do. 
Can anyone try to change my code or suggest his own code for those simple A,B classes, which will be easy to adjust to new classes (for example if will want to add some simple class C with 4 fields and the addition and subtraction operations between C and itself and between A and C and B and C), which will work as I described here and in the begging (pretty much the same actually).

**Redact after a few answers:**
The real domain of the new types:
So in the old problem, the Double type meant a deterministic value (its means that this value is known in real world with probability 1.0). 
Now I need to replace it with the system of types in the picture.
[image]
Now about the operation and operands functionality:
Every two object in the same branch should be operated as it first ancestor with him self.
Two objects of different branches should act like their first ancestors acts with same operation.

So eventually I want to refactor the code to the new assumption that:

```
event.getAttributeValue(index);
```

can return any of the classes in the described possible hierarchy. 
Of course right now I need to write a code that will implement only the two left most high objects and all the operations between them, as subtract, add, and so on. 
And my goal is to design the correct skeleton of interfaces and classes for this problem.

**Another clarification due to the last updated answer:**

what I want to do is some kind of wrapper and Functional as Strategy design pattern, something as in the two codes in the next links:

**first** (not templated example which I need to generalize according to the last updated answer): 
[first](https://ideone.com/nrCrK0)

**second** (something like this, but using Class, Class and both BiFunction, and BinaryOperator according to the suggested solution):
[second](https://ideone.com/4Ppdwt)

Comment: Yes, if you make everything abstract and any type goes then in the end, you've got nothing to base anything on. Furthermore, if you currently return a `Double` then you certainly have a very specific type, and it seems strange to me that you would use *the same method* and refactor all the code, not if you also want to keep `Double`. And in the end, if you have X types of `Operator` then you'll need N! amount of subtraction routines, which seems dumb. There is a reason why Java does almost all operations on `int` and not on `byte`, `short` and `char`.

Comment: I did'nt understand your comment. I want to keep the Double as same as to add new types, maybe just to wrap it, don't see how it can be possible for other types to interact as I want to. And lets assume that I don't have to have all the combinations of operands types for each operation, I want to leave the choice which to implement to the coder who will want to add a new type. So even if somebody want to add the N+1 new class to already implemented N, I want it will be able to add only the interactions between different types that he want to, it doesn't have to be all possible combinations.

Comment: If you see any simple solution as 'make all abstract' and it works for you, Ill be thankful if you just publish it as an answer with working sample, it would be easier to see.

Comment: You don't get what I was trying to communicate. You have too much freedom in your model, which makes it (near?) impossible to implement it without running into problems. Therefore you should reevaluate your design and the decisions you are currently making. Otherwise, in my belief, sooner or later you're going to stall and take a nose dive. As I don't know the specifics of your domain - only the abstractions you made for it-  I cannot help you with that. In short, the code is *too* generic to my taste.

Comment: Now I got you. That's something thats went through my mind. I'll try to talk about the real domain with my problem. All I can say that I think about it as a design pattern that answers the relationships of CAN-DO, so I dont expect anyone to generate cide which can do everything, but at least the skeleton, as I built it in my example. But people told me the use of instanceof to check the typing is not a good practice and I can make by using generics and it didnt went well for me. So Im asking how to make my code example a little bit more generic, without the instanceof checks, but somehow with

Comment: bounded parameters of interfaces. Or somethinh like that. But as I sayed ill describe soon the real domain and at least three types which have to work as AttributeValue I mentioned at the begining.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica, now I detailed about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a class for this:  [BinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html).

Forget about a wrapper class like AttributeValue.  Just let the Event continue to hold simple values like it did before, including Doubles, and pass in the combining operation as a BinaryOperator.

Casting to a generic type (like `T`) is an unsafe operation due to type erasure, so you will want to pass the type as well:

```
private <V> V calculateDelta(Event event,
                             Class<V> valueType,
                             BinaryOperator<V> operation) {

    V firstValue = valueType.cast(
        event.getAttributeValue(
            StockEventTypesManager.firstStockMeasurementIndex));

    V secondValue = valueType.cast(
        event.getAttributeValue(
            StockEventTypesManager.firstStockMeasurementIndex + 1));

    return operation.apply(firstValue, secondValue);
}
```

A call to that method would look like this:

```
Double delta =
    calculateDelta(eventToProcess, Double.class, (a, b) -> a - b);
```

**Update:**

You point out in a comment that the operands aren’t always of the same type.  In that case, you would use [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) instead of BinaryOperator:

```
private <V, U, R> R calculateResult(Event event,
                                    Class<V> firstValueType,
                                    Class<U> secondValueType,
                                    BiFunction<V, U, R> operation) {

    V firstValue = firstValueType.cast(
        event.getAttributeValue(
            StockEventTypesManager.firstStockMeasurementIndex));

    U secondValue = secondValueType.cast(
        event.getAttributeValue(
            StockEventTypesManager.firstStockMeasurementIndex + 1));

    return operation.apply(firstValue, secondValue);
}
```

*However,* it turns out you can do both!  You can have the above method, and also the first version as a convenience, for cases where you expect both values, and the result, to be the same type:

```
private <V> V calculateResult(Event event,
                              Class<V> valueType,
                              BinaryOperator<V> operation) {

    return calculateResult(event, valueType, valueType, operation);
}
```

**Clarifications:**

BiFunction and BinaryOperator are each functional interfaces—that is, an interface with exactly one abstract method.  (`static` and `default` methods are not abstract methods.)

This means a lambda can be used to represent it.  `(a, b) -> a - b)` is identical to this:

```
new BinaryOperator<Double>() {
    @Override
    public Double apply(Double a, Double b) {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

So, the lambda is in fact the BiFunction or BinaryOperator.

It doesn’t have to be a lambda.  It can also be a method reference:

```
private Double subtract(Double a, Double b) {
    return a - b;
}

// ...

Double delta =
    calculateResult(eventToProcess, Double.class, this::subtract);
```

You can, of course, make such a method more complex:

```
private Double probabilityFor(DiscreteDistribution d, Integer x) {
    Map<Integer, Double> probabilities = d.getProbabilities();
    return probabilities.getOrDefault(x, 0);
}

// ...

Double probability =
    calculateResult(eventToProcess,
                    DiscreteDistribution.class,
                    Integer.class,
                    this::probabilityFor);
```

You can also define operations on the complex objects themselves:

```
public class DiscreteDistribution {
    private final Map<Integer, Double> probabilities = new HashMap<>();

    // ...

    public Double probabilityOf(int x) {
        return probabilities.getOrDefault(x, 0);
    }
}

public class ValueCalculator {

    // ...

    Double probability =
        calculateResult(eventToProcess,
                        DiscreteDistribution.class,
                        Integer.class,
                        DiscreteDistribution::probabilityOf);

}
```

Comment: I just made the problem more specific, see if this implementation still fits the problem. 
In your suggestion where do I override the apply function ? 
And another question, as I described in the redaction, accordingly to the domain, there could be different types for first value and second value and the operation still has some semantics for that. Will it work ether with the BinaryOperation<V1,V2> operation ?
Or Do i need to implement my own BinaryOperation interface ?
Another accurate detail, it can be same typeand it can be different types in the same run.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: yes, that exactly the solution I was looking for. But, there is one another improvement of it I want to do. The reason I still want the wrapper class and some AttrValueFunctional , is because there are a lot of places where there is such "caculateResult" and kind of "calculateDelta" (a lot of this kind of calculations between one, two or more attributes values), so I want to create another level of abstraction, so the changes in the code of such calculate functions will be only as changing the type into the wrapper type AttrValue

Comment: (for example) and something as using my strategy pattern Functional for those AttrValue new types.  I'll add some example of the last code I wrote, which I need to generelize according what u suggested. It is still this solution, but with another level of abstraction. Maybe you even could write according to this only the skeleton with the template types of Class<V>, Class<U>, operation R.

Comment: I hope you understand what I'm willing to do, in other words I want to hide from the code where there is functions such as calculateDelta all this type casting and apply use into another inner Functional, as an abstraction.

Comment: I updated my question last time, although your answer is already very close to what I want to do, maybe you can once again show me how it should look like as a strategy design patter with a wrapper class with both BiFunction, and BinaryOperator.

Comment: Your request is difficult for me to understand.  A generalized “do any operation on any object” superclass doesn’t seem to have any use;  it seems to me that BinaryOperator and BiFunction already fulfill that role.

Comment: Yes, it is. I meant that I want to write all those calculate functions in one place, so I need I suppose a Functional with 3 parametric types, U, V, R, as I see it.  
I want to implemet it as in the book Thinking in Java Bruce Eckel on page 737 on the topic:
Using function objects as strategies 737. 
Your solution is answering the generalization problem, I didn't say it correctly, now I'm talking only about the design pattern of your solution. Suppose there a dozens of places in code where there are such calculate functions.

Comment: Now I dont want to change their signatures to parametric in every place, but I prefere to write all of the in one Functional class and wrap those Attribute Values in a wrapper, and every time I want to do with them something, Ill have to call some function of this Functional. If you look in Eckel's book, I think you will get how I want to design it. And that my last issue on that topic.

Comment: Page 737 of which edition?  The 4th edition seems to be discussing enums on page 737.  But going back to your various generalized operations:  How would you decide which operation is executed, given two objects?  Do their respective types determine it?

Comment: yes, corresponding to their types. Their will be an implementation of each BiFunction, or BinaryOperator correspondingly to their types in the same place. And just to clarify more, I dont want to to gather the calculate functions themselves, but the operations that they use, in our exmaple it was Math.Abs on Double and minus operator, so the DeltaCalculation will remain where it is.

I looked at the table of contents of the 4th edition here:
https://www.pearson.com/store/p/thinking-in-java/P100001035796?tab=table-of-contents

Comment: Only the operations will be in the utility or functional, that's how it called in that design pattern as much as I understood. The valueType cast and the operation.apply will be done in this Functional, separately from the code of calculateDelta, so it will remain non parametric, but the wrapper of each AttributeValue will hold it class type and that's how I will be able to do the cast on another place/level. Is that clear ? That's the idea I want to implement.